# Find preceding-sibling with specific name and without specific attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, schematron

I have a pretty big test checking order of things and I want to ignore `baz` elements with an attribute `attri` that is equal to `y`, this is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. It seems to be ignoring `baz` regardless of attribute:

Context:

```
jd:foo|jd:bar|jd:baz[@attri != 'y']|jd:bam
```

Test:

```
        (name()='foo' and 
          (preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='bar']
           or preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='baz' and @attri != 'y']
           or preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='bam']
          )
       ) or
       (name()='bar' and 
          (preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='baz' and @attri != 'y']
           or preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='bam']
          )
       ) or
       (name()='baz' and 
          (preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='bam']
          )
       )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context excludes not only `baz` elements that contain `@attri` equal to `y`, but also `baz` elements that contain *no* atrribute. This:

```
jd:baz[@attri != 'y']
```

says that `baz` *must* have an `@attri` attribute, and it also must not be `y`. So a node such as `<baz>...</baz>` will *not* be part of the context because it does not contain the attribute. This will include in the context elements like `<baz attri='z'>`.

If you wish to exclude only the `<baz attri='y'>` elements (but not the ones that don't have that attribute), you have to use:

```
baz[not(@attri = 'y')]
```

which selects all `baz` elements that have `@attri='y'` and negates that set. This *will* include elements that do not have a `@attri` attribute.

The same applies to your test, if elements without the attribute are to be considered.